# My New Site admin approval

Tags: installation, users

I'm planning to build a website with Drupal (having very little experience in building sites and none with Drupal). Through my webhost I managed to install Drupal on my site and I tried to create a drupal account immediately. I got an email "Account details....(Pending Admin Approval)", but then nothing. Maybe I'm just too eager and should just wait longer :-), but it could also be that I did something wrong. 
So my question: is it normal for an account to take more than 3 days getting My New Site admin approval? And can I do something to speed up the process?

I'm following some tutorials and wish I could play around a little while learning.
THanks for the info!
Hetty

Comment: When installing Drupal you should have had to set up a "site maintenance account" with a username and passowrd. This is the global admin account (user 1). You should be logging in to your site with this. There is no admin approval for this account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you installed Drupal you should have had to setup a main account:

[image: Setup User]

That is the login you should be using, if you don't know that password go to /user and click Forgot Password and you can retrieve your login if you remember username or email you used. Since you got (Pending Admin Approval) it should be that email that is registered as main account.

(Pending Admin Approval) emails are sent when someone else tries to register an account on your site.